# Can I shorten this? IE without percentage = being used twice?

Tags: python-3.4

```
percentage = int(input("\nWhat percentage of your bill would you like to calculate? "))
percentage = float(round(percentage / 100 * bill, 2))
```

Hi everyone

New to Python and wondering whether the above two lines of code can be shortened to only include 'percentage =' once?

As the 'percentage' variable is being defined by user input I am assuming until this is done I cannot define 'percentage' as an equation hence the two separate lines of code?

If it helps to understand the end goal, then here is the code as a whole - it's a simple tip calculator:

```
# Tip calculator
# calculates a %15 and %20 tip for any given meal
# code by c07vus


print("\nHello, welcome to tip calculator!")

bill = float(input("\nIn £'s what was the bill total? "))

fifteen = float(round(15 / 100 * bill, 2))

twenty = float(round(20 / 100 * bill, 2))

print("\nA %15 tip of your bill would be:", fifteen, "pounds")
print("\nA %20 tip of your bill would be:", twenty, "pounds")

print("\nYou can also calculate any percentage you like!")

percentage = int(input("\nWhat percentage of your bill would you like to calculate? "))
percentage = float(round(percentage / 100 * bill, 2))

print("\nThank you, your tip would be:", percentage, "pounds")

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit")
```

Thanks for all the help and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can put it in one line: Just put the expression that you assigned to `percentage` to where you use that value in the second line. But don't expect that line to be pretty, or readable...

```
percentage = float(round(int(input("\nWhat percentage of your bill would you like to calculate? ")) / 100 * bill, 2))
```

In general, I would stick with the version you have now. However, in this special case, I would instead rename the second variable, since that is no longer the percentage! It's the tip.

```
percentage = int(input("\nWhat percentage of your bill would you like to calculate? "))
tip = float(round(percentage / 100 * bill, 2))
```

Also, you do that calculation three times! That should be reason enough to make this a function:

```
to_tip = lambda percent: float(round(percent / 100 * bill, 2))
... # use that same function to calculate fifteen and twenty
tip = to_tip(percentage)
```

And finally, if you want to display the result to *exactly* two decimal places, using a format string is better than rounding.

```
print("\nThank you, your tip would be: {:.2f} pounds".format(tip))
```